# How do I display an image from a URL using a Variable to create the URL

Tags: javascript, image, url, variables

I am wishing to include an image in a page that will change each day.
My variable string calculation works (can display the url using  but am having problems working out how to put the variable as the url  this is what I have so far:

```
<script> 
var tD = new Date(); 
var datestr = "http://www.fakeurl.com/" + (tD.getMonth()+1) + "/" + tD.getDate() + ".jpg"; 
document.getElementById("+datestr+")
img src='"+ datestr +"' style="border: 0px;" /
</script>
```

What do I need to do different to get it to actually display my image?
I am a newby please help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make sure that the script will run after the IMG element has been loaded.

In order to insure this you need to use jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(myOnloadFunc);
```

or to use

```
<body onload="myOnloadFunc()">
```

While the JavaScript function myOnloadFunc() will include your original code.

There is a mistake in the original code you posted, please see my corrections.

```
var tD = new Date(); 
var datestr = "http://www.fakeurl.com/" + (tD.getMonth()+1) + "/" + tD.getDate() + ".jpg"; 
var imgElement = document.getElementById("imgElementID");
imgElement.src = datestr;
imgElement.style = "border: 0px;" ;
```

I think you mixed up the variable "datestr" with the IMG element.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
    var tD = new Date();
    var datestr = "http://www.fakeurl.com/" + (tD.getMonth()+1) + "/" + tD.getDate() + ".jpg";
    alert(datestr);
    document.getElementById("datestr").src = datestr;

    }
    </script>

----------------------
HTML:
<img id="datestr" src="" style="border: 0px;"/>
```

I hope this will help you....